# Transform file with multiheader, fillna and different formats

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have some Excel file with multiheader which requires some advanced steps on reading and cleaning.

[image]

1. The file could come with some extra lines above header(some files have row with "Sales Report" text, some - don't). So the script should automatically understand what is the positions of the headers (in some cases raws 4-7, in some cases - 3-6).
2. There are missing values in column names (next to material group and material). The script should fill those missing values with Material Group Name and Material Name respectively. Or in general - name of the column on the left + " Name" substring.
3. There are missing values in those columns, which should be filled with "ffill" method.
4. And finally - the file should be transformed to flat table style, so that final list of columns are:

Material Group | Material Group Name | Brand | Material | Material Name | Ean/UPC | Cal year month | Plant | Plant Name | Sales Qty | Sales at Retail with Tax

It looks, that this task requires advanced knowledge of Multiheader, so that we don't transform data using pivot table. The data (numbers) should be taken as it is, so that's why I am reading with dtype=str parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested few different solutions and found out, that the following approach works well:

1. Read file with pd.read_exce(nrows = 30)
2. Indentify number of index columns, their names etc.
3. Read the file again including parameters header and index.

This way the pandas will do this job really well. Transformation could be achieved with .stack and .reset_index methods on this dataframe.